# Update selected data from same table column as currency

Tags: mysql, select, update, format

I am trying to update selected data from a table column and format this data as currency.

My table column holds strings that have both mixed whole numbers and already formatted data. This was due to the fact that I had migrated old data which were whole numbers but any new data or updated old data gets formatted correctly in the application and database.

I would like to select all the non-formatted data from this table column  and then Update this data to currency format.
0 to 0.00,
200 to 200.00,
23702 to 23,702.00,
34000.00 to 34,000.00,
2954795.54 to 2,954,795.54

Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Format as currency preserve string datatype or change field datatype to currency?

Comment: Format non-formatted data as currency preserving datatype as string.

Comment: Simple update query. With `WHERE NOT INSTR(field,',')`.

Answer (score 1):

You really want to store data in fields of the correct *Data Type*. 
If these values are monetary amounts, then hold them in a suitable Data Type, like Currency.

Any time you convert data from one type to another, you're make extra work for the database engine, having to do the conversion, and running the risk of losing the benefit on any Indexes you might have defined, because calling a function on a field in every row generally forces the database to *Table Scan* that table (unless you have function-based Indexes, but that's another story).

Using the "wrong" Data Type also means that some functionality "doesn't work" properly.  If you're storing Numerical values as Strings, then comparing these values "goes all wrong".

For example, in the Numeric World ...

```
10 > 2  =>  TRUE
```

... as you'd expect, but in the *Character* world ...

```
'10' > '2'  =>  FALSE
```

Comment: For MySQL, "currency" is best held in something like `DECIMAL(11,2)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table
SET field = FORMAT(CAST(field AS DECIMAL(10, 2)), 2)
WHERE NOT INSTR(field,',')
```

Comment: I think that you don't need to call `CAST`; just use `FORMAT(field, 2)`